# How do I add guest checkout in react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, e-commerce

I want to build e-commerce website with only **guest checkout** in React. I don't have an authenticated user, so can't use session. Is there a way to implement this?

Comment: Use a browser cookie.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it.